# Electromagnets' relative strength of attraction & repulsion

Tags: electromagnetism

I have two small 12V electromagnets:

[image]

When powered oppositely they attract powerfully so that I cannot pull them apart.
But when they're connected the same way they repel only weakly and I can easily push them into contact.
Why the difference?
Thank-you,

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the magnetization of the iron core. When the directions are opposite, there is essentially no magnetic flux in the iron cores, almost no magnetization, so the iron does not contribute much to the force.

When the directions are such that the flux through the magnetic circuit is large, the iron is almost saturated, and it is hard to pull them apart. The holding power can be calculated by the energy required to open a small air gap.

Comment: Good, thank-you.  Is there any way to achieve a powerful repulsion? (Perhaps not having a circuit, ie just the inner iron with the windings, and no "outer" iron?)